# Set the correct constraints on textViews populated with Json

Tags: objective-c

I have 2 textViews that gets populated by some text I download using Json but I have a layout problem.

The data I download is used to create a product card, different products has different descriptions so I end up with some textViews that has scroll (because they have too much text) and other that has no scroll because the text isn't enough. What I want is that the textViews shouldn't scroll the text inside them but their height should be set based on the amount of text I download. Do I need to create them programmatically in order to have this kind of result or is it doable also using auto-layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did for the exact same thing:
I design designed UIView with a UILabel in it (rather than a UITextView) within XCode, later I gave a TAG to UILabel (associated to a constant for easy recall), then later recall those element with corresponding tag and set its height according to text size with this command:

```
[myLabel sizeToFit];
```

The problem is that if you have to readjust the container Y size and then any UIViews below for not overlapping each other, but it can be done easily.

Comment: does the sizeToFit auto adjust the number of line that the UILabel needs to use?
The overlapping is not a big deal since I can just put a constrait for top space between the elements, the other problem I have is that the main view is a ScrollView so I need to auto resize it based on the height of my 2 textViews

Comment: Yes it resizes the view. The whole point is that you have to do some calculation to readjust all the Y view, and of course  to finally resize the UIScrollView based on calculation you have made.